# Consuming a context within another context in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I currently have 2 contexts within my React app and I was trying to call a method from my top-level context within my 2nd context.

Here is how the context are nested:

App.js

```
function App(props) {

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider>
      <APIContextProvider>
         // I have some components here
      </APIContextProvider>
    </SessionContextProviders>
  )
}
```

is there a way to consume the SessionContext within my APIContextProvider?

```
import { SessionContext } from 'contexts/session'

export const APIContext = createContext();

export default class APIContextProvider extends Component {

    static contextType = SessionContext

    randomMethod() {
        this.context.logoutUser()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <APIContext.Provider value={{randomMethod: this.randomMethod}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </APIContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

The issue is that when running randomMethod within my APIContext doesn't work because this.context is undefined.

Is this feasible or am I missing something?

Comment: consuming context without `<xxxContext.Consumer/>`? read docs

Comment: @xadm Using `Context.Consumer` will re-render all its children based on a value. I don't think, that this is, what the OP asks for.

Comment: @Kluddizz using `useContext` does exactly the same, it will be rerendered, too

Comment: @xadm You're right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created an example for you, where `ApiProvider` uses `logoutUser` from `SessionContext` and providing `randomMethod`, which calls the function `logoutUser`.

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";

const SessionContext = createContext();

const SessionProvider = props => {
  const logoutUser = () => {
    alert("Logout user, but fast!");
  };

  return (
    <SessionContext.Provider value={logoutUser}>
      {props.children}
    </SessionContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { SessionContext as default, SessionProvider };
```

Inner context

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import SessionContext from "./SessionContext";

const ApiContext = createContext();

const ApiProvider = props => {
  const logoutUser = useContext(SessionContext);

  const randomMethod = () => {
    logoutUser();
  };

  return (
    <ApiContext.Provider value={{ randomMethod: randomMethod }}>
      {props.children}
    </ApiContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ApiContext as default, ApiProvider };
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <ApiProvider>
        <TestComponent />
      </ApiProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-bush-959st

Comment: Awesome Kluddizz, Thanks for your thorough answer.

It worked changing my context definitions from class (Component inheritation) components to functional components and using the Hook API.

I don't understand though: where was I using both?
All my components (including my two contexts) are defined using Component and inheritation except for App.js

Where is my implementation breaking?

Comment: Yes, the mixing was related to your App.js, which was functional. Your other components were class definitions.

Comment: Ok, I just need to add, after reading the comments, there is absolutely nothing wrong with mixing class based and functional components separately. It would only be wrong to put functional hooks in a class component

Comment: Also the term is inheritance, not inheritation